# Not receiving the data from Node JS and use it in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to connect NodeJS and send some data to React JS for it to use. The information is being sent when I access the backend, but React JS receives an empty object {}. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Might the problem be related to CORS? Or do I have to use JSON.parse(r)? Not sure.

index.js

```
const a = "sup"

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    console.log("someone is here")
    res.status(200).json({
        data:a
    })
})


app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running")
})
```

Homepage.jsx

```
class Homepage extends Component {

    state = {
        authenticated: false,
        data:""
    };



    async componentDidMount(){
        const url = "http://localhost:3000"
        const r = await fetch(url, {
            mode: "no-cors",
            method: "GET",
            headers: 
              {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}

          })
        const data = await JSON.stringify(r)
        console.log(data)
    }

    render() { 


        return ( <h1>{this.state.data}</h1> );
    }
}
```

**UDPATE:**

I had a port issue usage issue and incorrect usage of componentDidMount(). I managed to improve the code as recommended by users. NodeJS and ReactJS were pointing to port 3000. I reassigned the ports (NodeJS:3000, ReactJS:4000). ReactJS is now making a fetch call to "http://localhost:3000". However, I now get 2 errors:

```
1) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
2) Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")

const a = "sup"

app.use(cors({
        origin:"http://localhost:4000",
        methods:"GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
        credentials:true
    }))

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
})

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    console.log("someone is here")
    res.status(200).json({
        data:a
    })

})


app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running")
})
```

**Homepage.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Homepage extends Component {

    state = {
        data:[]
    };

     componentDidMount(){
        const url = "http://localhost:3000"
        fetch(url)
        .then(r=>r.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({data}))

    }

    render() { 
        return ( <h1>{this.state.data ? this.state.data : "loading"}</h1> );
    }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: You probably want to use `json()` on the fetch statement to extract the JSON data. This is seen in most example of [using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have express installed and initialised into const app.
Then:

On the backend:

```js
const data = "Sup"

app.use(
"/",
  (req, res)=>{
   res.status(200).send(data);
  }
);
```

On the front end- Inside componentDidMount:

```js
const url="http://localhost:3000"
axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ data: data })
      console.log(this.state.users)
     })
```

Comment: I'm getting these errors: 
1)
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
2)
GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_FAILED
3)Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Do you have cors unstalled?

Comment: I'm not using it in the backend. I have it commented out. This is what I have: 
app.use(
    cors({
        origin:"http://localhost:3000",
        methods:"GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
        credentials:true
    }))

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
})

Comment: Please, uncomment that. app.use(cors()); in your express should do

Comment: I uncommented everything and now I'm getting this message: "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...". The array in the state "data" comes back empty when I console.log it.

Comment: Could you change the backend to listen to port 8000 instead of 3000. I assume React also runs on port 3000

Comment: When I run the backend, it runs on port 3000. React runs on port 3001.

Comment: I noticed I had a port issue. I changed the ports (backend:3000, react:4000)The API was fetching at the correct port. The API was fetching through the correct port (3000). However, the backend had the wrong origin port. I changed the port to 4000 to accept calls from the ReactJS API. Now, I'm getting these error messages: 1) GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE  2) Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: I added axios as you said, but I get back an empty array. []

Comment: What did you want to achieve with this backend code snippet? : res.status(200).json({
        data:a
    })

Comment: Only to receive the data in the React API and display it

Answer (score 0):

```
class Homepage extends Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
    authenticated: false,
    data: ""
  };

 }


  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000"
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        data: data
      }));
  }

  render() {
    return ( < h1 > {
        this.state.data ? this.state.data : 'loading';
      } < /h1> );
    }
  }
```

Please, update your class component. The fetch in componentDidMount() was not as expected. You need not use await in fetch because, this async action when ever its done, the state gets updated and react renders the updates. Please, watchout for the response you send via API and set the state accordingly. Here, I have set to data considering the api sample you have provided in the question. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting this error, "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled." I try to include {mode:"no-cors"} in the fetch, but it doesn't work.